# How to have full screen UITableView (with header) in iPhone X?

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, xcode9

I'm updating my app with Xcode 9 for the iPhone X compatibility.
I use auto layout and "Use safe Area Layout Guide" is marked.

I have a header in my UITableView, and, as you can see in the screenshot below, the header view strictly respects the top safe area. 
The header doesn't follow my tableview top constraint (which is bigger than the safe area)

[image]

My tableview constraints :

[image]

How can I do to modify my header in order to fill the top of the screen (white area on the screenshot)?

Comment: From the picture you posted, notice equals: 45 for top layout guide. Make it 0.

Comment: Did you figure it out..?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava yep constraints issue !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's probably due to your constraints are badly set.

You just need to change the top constraint of your Header by double clicking on it.

The screen where you should double click:

[image: The screen where you should double click]

And change the Safe Area constraint by the Superview item.

[image: here]

Comment: I"ve added header programatically, how can I do this?

Comment: @Feroz Set preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins of your rootViewController to true might help. After, you need to activate your top constraint

Comment: @Feroz have you figured out how to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 39):

In the size inspector of your tableview, set Content Insets to Never

Comment: Thanks. Helped me a lot

Comment: That's spot on !

Comment: This helped me too!

Comment: Programmatically, this is done by setting `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` (Swift 4.2)

Comment: Perfect! It should be an accepted answer!

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this **set the top area of the table with respect to the superview instead of safearea.**

In viewdidload, write this

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = false;
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never;
}
```